# What are signals in electrical and electronics?

Tags: signal-processing

Recently in lectures we've begun talking about how signals can be varied by modulation, how the Fourier Series and Fourier Transform help, etc. but I'm stuck understanding it at a more basic level because I don't really know what a signal is, where it comes from, how it's produced, etc. from a physical perspective.

If anyone could help, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(electrical_engineering)

Answer (score 1):

In electrical and electronics, and fields of study which use those like radar and microwave/wireless communications, it is mostly the electromagnetic field, usually modeled by the electric field as a function of space and time, containing instantaneous amplitude and phase (thus also frequency). You can include polarization by having amplitude be a vector.

There's plenty good books on basic signal processing, if you need to do something on it worthwhile get one. I used Oppenheimer and Schafer, for practical signal processing long time ago, I'm sure there's better ones now. Also some more general as well, like something on signal analysis. Good ones will include things like modulation (including modern ones, analog and digital) but lots more, also detections, estimation of parameters, error coding and correction, etc, and some of the digital signal issues. More practical ones will give you the DSP.

Answer (score 0):

A signal can be anything that transfers information. Usualy we talk about signals in electronics when we are trying to measure a quantity. The measuring device has an output over which it sends a signal which we can then interpret.
In electronics that signal is nothing else than voltage or a current, or anything that tells you something about some property you're trying to measure.

Let's say for example that you're trying to measure temperature. You have a sensor that you've put in a fluid. That sensor produces voltage depending on it's temperature. This voltage is then transfered to a device that can read the magnitude of that voltage. Since we know experimentaly or theoreticaly what voltage Will be produced at specific temperatures we can interpret that "SIGNAL" as a temperature. In this case a signal is a difference in potential between 2 parts of the sensor, but it could be sending electromagnetic waves (light) or current.

So in short: A signal is what we use to transfer information. This might not always be the case, but I think this helps you intuitively.